# Okular in ubuntu cannot perform "selection" and copying&pasting

Tags: linux, okular

A "selection" tool in my okular 0.19.3 (soft -- ubuntu, 14-04) allows me to choose only one of those: "selection tool", "text selection tool", and "table selection tool". I need only "text selection tool". However when I choose it, my mouse cannot make rectangular around the text I want -- the mouse simply cannot do anything. If I choose "selection tool", a little window invites me to make rectangular  around the text/image I want, and once I did it, it suggest that "Image (of such and such size) is ready to be copied to clipboard", but any attempt to paste it into clipboard fails. I do remember that when it was working on my old machine, it would state "text" instead of "image", and worked perfectly well. Is there anything I can do about it? Oh, I forgot to say that my "clipboard" is a "vim" window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to find the answer and cure. The faulty part was my .vimrc (well, precisely speaking, me -- for not being too thorough..). I've now included two lines in my .vimrc:

vmap  y
imap  P

The first one  enabled me to copy text from PDF-file when using Okular. I could choose either "selection tool" or  "text selection tool" mode. They work a bit differently: "selection tool" show me TWO little windows that offer me to either choose "text selection" or "image selection" (I choose "text") after I make a rectangular over the chosen text, and then I can paste the text into my "vi" window. If I choose "text selection" , it simply change the color of my selected text, and I can paste it right away into my "vi" window. Most amazingly, by using either one of them, I can copy even equations i. e. all Greek letters are properly copied into vi file!!! (I don't know how they do that...)

Comment: Gosh! -- another round of troubles -- it turns out that not ANY pdf-file is good for that selection function of Okular! Those that were generated by my "groff" command ARE NOT GOOD. I need now to generate ps-file by my groff, then translate them into "pdf" bu using "ps2pdf file.ps>file.pdf", and only then everything worked...

Answer (score 0):

The text selection tool doesn't select a rectangle.  It selects the text as a sequence of characters from where you press the mouse button until you release it.  At least it does so with a current Okular 16.04.1 under Fedora.  I can't easily check on an old Ubuntu, so there might have been some bug that have been fixed in the mean time.

I wasn't aware you could paste images into vim.  It's a text editor, not a graphical tool.  How would you do that?  Have you done it previously?

I tried selecting an image with the selection tool as you describe and paste it into a gimp buffer, and that worked just fine.

Comment: right, that is what I was trying to say -- I need to copy into my vim window a TEXT (and Okular does it with the help of a mouse that makes a rectangular around chosen text). And of course, it cannot copy an image into vim window. But I need it to copy/paste TEXT, and it doesn't work... My Okular release is 0.19.3, and I don't know whether it well updated one...